# Accessing object by string name

Tags: javascript, eval

In my node js application I have a variable (name) that contains an object's name; I need to assign that object to another object's property; I do this:

```
wrapElement[index].model = eval('model.' + name);
```

Jshint throws a well-documented warning for that (eval can be harmful);
I know eval can be dangerous (but in this case i think I'm safe because 'name' is not an input from user) and bad for performance;

In this case do I really need to use eval() or there is a better way to accomplish this assignement?

### --- UPDATE -----------------

As suggested below in comments, in this case I can simply do model[name] instead of eval().
The code of this application has been changed just today, keeping models in a separate node module and exported as 'model';
before models were defined in the same file:

```
Shop = {
    ...
}
Offer = {
    ...
}
```

And the assignement was:

```
wrapElement[index].model = eval(name);
```

In this case I was not able to write

```
something[name]
```

instead of using eval;
In this case, should I include all the models (Shop, Offer, ...) into a wrappingObject in order to write wrappingObject[name] or I can access it with somethingElse[name]?

Comment: `wrapElement[index].model = model[name];`

Comment: I find it kind of amusing that you are using bracket notation and `eval` in a single expression. Do you know what `wrapElement[index]` actually does?

Comment: You are right; this come from a recent change in the code (now model is exported from another module so I can do model[name] as suggested; just before the code was eval(name) so I was not able to write it like something[name]...

Comment: About your edit: Yes, you must use a wrapping object, or make them global so you can access them like `window[name]`.